# Is Prague known for their Marionette / Puppet shows?

Tags: culture, prague, entertainment

I'm not sure if it's **Prague** or all of Eastern Europe in general that are known for their **Marionette/Puppet shows** (or if I'm mistakenly projecting it on the majestic city), but is Prague a place to catch a performance of Marionette/Puppet shows to get a taste of the culture?

I know this is a pretty touristy thing to do (at least in my mind), but would there be many shows in the **English language** that are **enjoyable for adults** to watch?

**Any places in Prague one would recommend going to catch a delightful show?**

*It doesn't necessarily have to be in English, (hello! I'm in their country!) but if there is a famous story-line that I would understand regarldess of language that would be terrific!

*How much do they cost to attend anyhow?

Comment: Not sure about shows (I didn't look/don't remember), but there sure were a lot of marionette dolls for sale so it seems like Prague must be known for it! I bought a marionette doll there! If you find a show, I'll be jealous if you go because that seems fantastic. It's like a fairy-tale land! Good luck!

Comment: Search queries like "Marionette theatre in prague for adults" seem to give decent results on Google.

Comment: I saw lots of marionettes for sale in Prague, but don't remember ads for shows. Prague's famous show is the black theatre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is Prague a place to catch a performance of Marionette/Puppet shows to get a taste of the culture?

As a Prague local I've never heard of the puppet shows, nor are they particularly well-known in the Czech culture. So I won't say visiting the puppet theater would help you get immersed in the "local culture". It is mostly a touristy thing, just like the numerous hansom cabs and cabarets.

> but would there be many shows in the English language that are enjoyable for adults to watch?

The most well-known theater is called [National Marionette Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Marionette_Theatre). Their most frequent show is Don Giovanni and as you can see from this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7w1oLIF9BA), it is an Opera in Italian. Therefore no Czech language knowledge is needed.

> Any places in Prague one would recommend going to catch a delightful show?

The other two puppet theaters in Prague are [Divadlo Říše loutek](http://www.riseloutek.cz/program/) and [Divadlo Zvoneček](http://www.zvonecek.info/home.php). Both of them only host children shows in Czech, therefore it's probably not interesting for a tourist.

> How much do they cost to attend anyhow?

They cost 500-600 CZK per person, which is around 25 EUR at the moment.

Comment: For me, the first few times I visited Prague, in the early 1990s, it was difficult to avoid touristy mentions of the city's puppet shows.

Comment: @MastaBaba you also get plenty of brothel advertisements, but I wouldn't say it's a hardcore part of Czech culture...

Comment: If you say so. Those puppet theater promotions were something I don't typically experience elsewhere. Nor, for that matter, plenty of brothel announcements.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so common to see them in the street but you can definitely find a pop-out artist playing with Marionette at Charles Bridge. I see him any time passing by between Old Town and Lesser Town across Vltava River.

Edit ex post

There is [Spejbl & Hurvínek Theater](http://www.spejbl-hurvinek.cz/en/). You may have already heard of these characters.